# I want to send call notification from terminal using .pem

Tags: swift, terminal, apple-push-notifications, callkit

I want to send call notification using `terminal` and `.pem` file. all code looking good at my end. terminal throw this error.

[image]

`pushregistrytoken` retrieve from app and try this command on terminal.

`curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' --http2 --cert Certificates.pem:1234 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/pushregistrytoken`

here i use `http2` protocol

Resource : https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy

i am working with terminal to send notification for first time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old certificate and password way is no longer works ,you need to create an **AuthKey.p8** along with it's **authKey** and replace the entries here according to your developer settings , then wrap the below code inside **File.sh** and execute it from terminal **$ bash pathToFile/File.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

deviceToken="tokenHere"
authKey="pathTo........./AuthKey.p8"
authKeyId="......."
teamId="........"
bundleId="........"
endpoint="https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com:2197"
apns_collapse_id="send_update"

read -r -d '' payload <<-'EOF'
{
   "aps": {
      "badge": 2,
      "category": "mycategory",
      "alert": {
         "title": "my title",
         "subtitle": "my subtitle",
         "body": "my body text message 103"
      }
   },
   "custom": {
      "id": "1234"
   }
}

EOF

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

base64() {
   openssl base64 -e -A | tr -- '+/' '-_' | tr -d =
}

sign() {
   printf "$1"| openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign "$authKey" | base64
}

time=$(date +%s)
header=$(printf '{ "alg": "ES256", "kid": "%s" }' "$authKeyId" | base64)
claims=$(printf '{ "iss": "%s", "iat": %d }' "$teamId" "$time" | base64)
jwt="$header.$claims.$(sign $header.$claims)"

curl --verbose \
   --header "content-type: application/json" \
   --header "authorization: bearer $jwt" \
   --header "apns-topic: $bundleId" \
   --header "apns-collapse-id: $apns_collapse_id"\
   --http2 \
   --data "$payload" \
   $endpoint/3/device/$deviceToken
```

Comment: how can i get jwt?

Comment: You don't need to change any content below `EOF # -----------`